# Open Appleworks 6 Database file?

Tags: appleworks

I have an appleworks 6 database file (.cwk), but no Mac with an old enough version of OS X to run Appleworks 6.  While pretty much all other appleworks files can be opened with something else, I can't find anything that will import a database.

Do I have any options?  Can I emulate an older OS X? (I still have my AppleWorks 6 CD, so can install).  Am I missing a program that can import it?  Is my only real solution to try and resurrect my dead PowerBook G4?

Comment: [I had offered the following as an answer, but Jason's response let me know it was not a good one. I deleted it and moved it here as a comment.] "The open source office suite LibreOffice (https://www.libreoffice.org) can open AppleWorks6 .cwk database files, although it probably will not do so with the formatting completely intact. Still, LibreOffice is a free install, and (assuming things go well) it offers a number of useful filetype choices for exporting your files to a handier format.

Comment: What do you see when you try opening the file in Numbers.app? How about when launching LibreOffice Calc and then openig the .cwk file?

Comment: bah! Calc tries to do a text import and the contents make it clear this is an alias file.  Guess I have some digging to do to find the actual file

Comment: Well, that explains why it wouldn't open. Best of luck to you.